# Chrome browser: not set cookie from response header

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

Create cookie on server side and then added to response:

```
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("foo", "bar");
    cookie.setPath("/abc");
    cookie.setDomain(request.getServerName());
    cookie.setSecure(request.isSecure());
    cookie.setMaxAge(24 * 60 * 60 * 90); //  90 days
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

response header: (not ajax) seen from browser developer tools

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 25 Feb 2015 07:13:12 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:foo="bar"; Version=1; Domain=localhost; Max-Age=7776000; Expires=Tue, 26-May-2015 07:13:12 GMT; Path=/abc
```

But from develop tools > resources > cookies, the cookie was not shown up.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Some questions: 1. Are you creating `Set-cookie` string by yourself? 2. Response is returned from localhost? 3. Are there other cookies in this domain? 4. For what is `Version=1;`?

Comment: edited. I did not set Version, it was added by Cookie API implicitly. The server name is localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Even I have written the same code but the cookie was not shown up.

When I print my response i will get the value, but i can not see on my chrome browser.

Server side code :

```
Cookie lastConnetionDateCookie = createCookie("lastConnetionDate", lastLoginDate);
            response.addCookie(lastConnetionDateCookie);

            Cookie creationDateCookie = createCookie("creationDate", userCreationDate);
            response.addCookie(creationDateCookie);

            Cookie servicesCookie = createCookie("services", StringUtils.join(services, "|"));
            response.addCookie(servicesCookie);

            _log.info(response);
```

Ajax code :

```
function setUserCookies() {
    JQ.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://.....',
        data: formToJSON,
        contentType:'application/json',
        /* xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }, */
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
             console.log('Cookie created successfully');
          },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             console.log('setUserCookies error : ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function formToJSON() {
    return ${userCookies};
}
```